# Placing Breakpoints and debugging other projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, breakpoints

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 Solution(C#) Containing multiple projects.
There is a services project containing services that I am using from my main UI Project.
When debugging I can only debug the main starting project. Is there a way to place breakpoints in my other project and debug them at runtime when my main project is using them?

Hope I was clear on my question
Thank you very much for any answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should be able to just place breaking points in the other project. Make sure you are in Debug mode, and also check your other project's web.config or app.config file and make sure that debug="true" and not "false."

Comment: thanks. the other projects had debug set to "false" that's why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

### yes you can!

build your other projects and place .dll and .pdb files in your running projects references folder where you place other projects reference files).

place break point in reference calling method in your running project and press <kbd>f11</kbd> when it breaks. now you will be able to debug other project files